# What item's effects or heroes' skills goes through Black King Bar?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Someone told me that Bane's ultimate goes through Black King Bar. Are there other item effects or hero skills that can disable thorough it and that can be used to counter heroes that heavily rely on this item?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Noteworthy disables and interrupts that go through magic immunity from various heroes (all ultimates):

- Bane
- Beastmaster
- Batrider
- Pudge
- Silencer
- Clockwerk
- Faceless Void
- Enigma
- Vengeful Spirit
- Magnus

Other ultimates that are primarily used for their damage still stun or ministun (but won't damage) magic immune opponents, useful for enemies who are trying to BKB and use a TP Scroll to escape.

- Necrolyte
- Anti-Mage
- Lich
- Juggernaut (Will still damage, as it deals physical damage.)
- Sniper's Assassinate
- Terrorblade's Sunder

Some other ultimates will slow through magic immunity:

- Shadow Demon
- Viper

The only non-ultimates that disable through a BKB are:

- Axe's Call
- Naga's Ensnare
- Meepo's Earthbind
- Lone Druid's Bear's Entangling Claws
- Faceless Void's Time Lock
- Slardar's Bash
- Abyssal Blade

Comment: you forgot enigma which is pretty huge vs magic immune units

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's also Lich's ult who procs a mini stun on the first target. A lot of people don't know this. It's very useful in the TP case you mentioned. Needs testing though, I can do it tomorrow if needed.

Comment: You're correct, no need to test.

Comment: Could you add alchimist's Unstable Concoction? It's damage cannot be juked with bkb and therefore can be good vs heroes relying on armlet and bkb. Furthermore if you add Viper for its slow we should add beastmaster's boar. Or is this question specifically for disabling? Then it should be rephrased

Comment: @Wandang I've interpreted the question as only disables. If I include spells that damage, there are a ton more, so I'll leave as is. If you want to update with those or rephrase the question, feel free.

Comment: Duel from Legion Commander goes through bkb

Comment: @RayofCommand Feel free to edit, plenty of improvements possible here.

Answer (score 2):

Any spell that has the [ultimate](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Ultimate) property will ignore the magic immunity from BKB.  However, generally the damage aspect of the ultimate will not work as damage is rarely considered an ultimate property.  Usually the secondary effects such as stun, slow, etc will ignore BKB.

There are a few ultimates listed that do not go through [magic immunity](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Magic_Immunity) at all:

1. Ravage - Impale effect is considered a non-ultimate
2. Finger of Death - Only deals damage and would be wasted
3. Laguna Blade - Only deals damage and would be wasted
4. Dream Coil - Doesn't stun or damage
5. Nether Strike - Doesn't work

Comment: Does this apply for normal dota?

Answer (score 1):

All auras affect magic immune units both positive and negative.

This includes Beastmaster, Shadow Fiend, all item auras, Skeleton King, healing aura from Juggernaut ward, Omni, etc.

Fun thing to do against teams that have a slow attacking carry as their main carry like Tiny who at lv 16 with Aghs, Phase, Drums Manta has less than 100 attack speed or against bad teams that are extremely auto attack carry heavy:

Pick Omni (-28% IAS), pick Tuskarr (-60% IAS) and have one of them buy a Shiva (-40% IAS) which adds up to -130% IAS (enchantress' untouchable is -120% and only for herself so it's equivalent to giving your entire team untouchable).

Watch them cry as they never complete their auto attack animations.

Also bash from basher item and troll warlord's melee goes through magic immunity.