# Are there any spells that can stop Juggernaut while spinning?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Are there any spells that will cause **Yurnero's** *(Juggernaut)* **Blade Fury** to stop?

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58487/what-items-effects-or-heroes-skills-goes-through-black-king-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

- Doom Bringer's Doom: http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=51753
- Void's Chronosphere: http://forum.gamesports.net/dota/showthread.php?11809-void-chronosphre-and-juggernaut-blade-fury

I'm sure more can be found

Comment: Also Tiny's toss (if you throw the Juggernaut; you can't target the Juggernaut with Toss).

Answer (score 1):

False. Both Doom Bringer's Doom and Void's Chronosphere can stop the spinning effect and the magic immunity, but he still does damage in an area around him.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Also, the mechanics may differ between Dota and Dota 2 so I would just be clear which game you are talking about.

Comment: Interesting... if this is true it's probably a bug.