# Does a gem / a sentry ward or dust reveal Slark's Shadow Dance?

Tags: dota-2

I wonder if a gem / a sentry ward or dust  reveals Slark's Ultimate "Shadow Dance".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slark is not entirely invisible, as one can still see the little cloud he hides in. This means that he can't be directly targeted rather than being plain invisible.

As to answer the question: **No**, GoTS and Wards do not reveal Slark (neither does anything else).

Plenty of spells can hit him while "Invisible" though, as stated [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58487/what-items-effects-or-heroes-skills-goes-through-black-king-bar)

Comment: yep I know that you see the cloud, but I wondered what can make him visible. I was not 100% sure if I am correct, so thank you for answering.

Comment: Appreciated. Still, the concept of Slark's invisibility - although mechanically is closer to actual invisiblity - feels like it's strategic use is closer related to the BKB

Comment: Yeah, off the top of my head, the only AoE stun that goes through BKB is Warlock's ult.

Comment: There are quite a few others, like Enigma's Black Hole, Faceless Void's Chronosphere and Clockwerk's hookshot. Here's a bigger list... http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58487/what-items-effects-or-heroes-skills-goes-through-black-king-bar

Comment: @Costa I never said that Shadow Dance is mechanically the same as BKB. I even said that it resembles it from a **strategic** point of view, as in "It prevents you from being targeted in a fight, granting highly increased survivability by not being able to target". It's not even closely related to BKB mechanics wise.

Comment: after the latest big patch, chronosphere does not anymore reveal slark :) if you want to update that, feel free